# How to differentiate parent and child tag while dom parsing?

Tags: android, dom, xml-parsing

I am using dom xml parser in android. In my source xml contains same name for parent and child.

How to differentiate parent tag and child tag while parsing xml data?

This is my sample xml.

```
<alerts>
    <alert>
       <code>QWEOS</code>
       <alert>this is alert1</alert>
       <description>this is description</description>
     </alert>
     <alert>
       <code>SDFHP</code>
       <alert>this is alert2</alert>
       <description>this is description</description>
     </alert>      
</alerts>
```

Comment: Can you please add some code or may be a snippet of your XML will be helpful...

Comment: you should not have same names for parent and childs...it makes no sence for me. i recommend to you change their names to avoid future problems...

Comment: @Shekhar Chikara: This is my xml.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an document doc.

```
 NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("parentnode");

    Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
    flag =XMLfunctions.getValue(e,"childnode");
```