# How to get elements between tags - JSoup

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

I'm parsing data from a site with JSoup on Android and I want to get all data from the first `<h3>` tag to the next `<h3>`

Example code:

```
<h3>First</h3>
<p>Start</p>
<p>0</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>

<h3>Second</h3>

<p>End</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
```

So I want to get

`Start 0 1 2 3` to be in one TextField

`End 4 5 6 7` to be in another TextField and so on

How can I do this ?

Comment: You've described your goal, but what have you tried so far to accomplish this? Have you run into a problem writing code to do what you want?

Comment: Explore the `Element` object after you parse your HTML into a `Document`

Comment: I think that you could find the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534456/jsoup-how-to-get-all-html-between-2-header-tags

Comment: I answered a similar question once in some detail. it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25502418/2229229