# Parsing text fields into excel columns

Tags: python, excel, parsing, text, vbscript

I've attempted to parse out data that's over 20,000 records. Each record has 4 fields that's prefixed with 2 alphanumeric values. Below is an example with 2 records. I currently have a bloated solution that uses Java based on the link here: [Parsing HTML Data using Java (DOM parse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491424/parsing-html-data-using-java-dom-parse). But I'm not looking to use that solution as it is overkill for just seperating the records. Is there a solution that uses VBS, Python or any other language that can separate out the fields based on the logic I've used already? Or another logical approach?

```
     100000000          SMP008483
  |---   Category                Western
  |---   Model                   Ford
  |---   Asset Delivered Date    ?
  |---   Scheduled               ?

     100000001          SMP008484
  |---   Category                Eastern
  |---   Model                   Chevrolet
  |---   Asset Delivered Date    ?
  |---   Scheduled               ?
```

Expected output is here:

```
ID1            ID2          Category    Model       Asset Delivered Date    Scheduled                           
100000000      SMP008483    Western     Ford                ?                   ?
100000001      SMP008484    Eastern     Chevrolet           ?                   ?
```

Comment: If you are open to using another format I would suggest JSON as it'll give you the hierarchy you need and is easily read by many languages. It would not take much Python code to parse this by opening a file, iterating through each line, and using string routines like `text.split()` or `test.partition()` to build up an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Where is this data?  Is it formatted exactly as you show, as plain text?

Comment: @TimWilliams The data is now exactly as shown after updating the data in the original question (based on spaces). The data is from a TXT file.

Comment: If you want to parse this then it should not be too difficult: you have predictable 5-row blocks and what looks like a fixed-width format. Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0):

This one is kinda crappy but it works. here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while IFS= read -r line;do
echo $line | egrep -q '^[0-9]+'
if test $? -eq 0; then
  id1=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1)
  id2=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)
  ((i++))
fi
echo $line | egrep -q 'Category'
if test $? -eq 0; then
  cat=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/^.*Category//')
  ((i++))
fi
echo $line | egrep -q 'Model'
if test $? -eq 0; then
  model=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/^.*Model//')
  ((i++))
fi
echo $line | egrep -q 'Asset Delivered Date'
if test $? -eq 0; then
  date=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/^.*Asset Delivered Date//')
  ((i++))
fi
echo $line | egrep -q 'Scheduled'
if test $? -eq 0; then
  sch=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/^.*Scheduled//')
  ((i++))
fi
if test $i -eq 5; then
  echo -e "${id1}\t${id2}\t${cat}\t${model}\t${date}\t${sch}"
  i=0
fi
done <<< "$(cat ${1})"
```

*Do not forget of adding all fields, because it will break if you do.

Comment: is it possible to have this edited so that multiple words can be used per field?

Comment: yeah, it could be edited easily by changing the 'cut' command with something more "versatile" like a sed. I'll do that later today.

Comment: done. it's still a quick script with almost no validation whatsoever though, but it works if the input is there.

Comment: Hi, thanks so far, but what do you mean by "*Do not forget of adding all fields, because it will break if you do."

Comment: It basically means that if for some reason you forgot to add a field entry, like for example the 'Model' field in one of your entries, then the script will break, because he needs to 'see' all 5 field lines per entry. they dont need to be in order but they need to be together and be exactly 5, not more nor less or it will break. I think that's not a big issue though.

Comment: Understood. One more thing, it appears my output is currently:

Comment: '10000000 ?ord   SMP008483'

Comment: '10000000 ?asternSMP008484'

Comment: I've attempted to troubleshoot this, but cannot get the correct full fields in line.

Comment: That's weird. It works just fine on my system. Which version of bash are you using?

Comment: I'm using GNU bash on a Raspberry Pi using Bash Version 4.2.37(1) release

Comment: I just tried another bash shell on Linux Ubuntu using version 4.2.25(1) and same problem exists. Is it related to spacing...carriage returns?

Comment: Hi, I think I found the issue. Indeed, it's related to carriage returns. the script works just fine as long as the input file is using unix format, probably yours is using dos format. to fix that just run dos2unix command to convert your file. *this commands changes your file so if you want to keep a copy, do it before you run the command.